# Historical Forward Exchange rates for QAR (Saudi Riyal)

Tags: data-request

I need data of 3-month Forward exchange rates between 5 pairs of currencies. Saudi Arabia Riyal (QAR or SAR) on one hand; and 5 currencies, USD, GBP, CHF, EUR, CNY on the other hand. I need quarterly data for period 2000-2015. I can find spot rates, but desperate to find forward rates. I can pay small amount of money, if anybody can help. Need urgently

Comment: (Probably you know more, but) SAR is pegged to the USD (at 3.75, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudi_riyal#Fixed_exchange_rate)). Also, QAR is Qatari Riyal, not Saudi.